# WorkManager: is there a way to see the constraints that were specified for a WorkRequest?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

The title says it all: I want to be able to see which constraints were specified for a specific WorkRequest, after work execution had already begun. This sounds like a basic functionality, yet I've just spent 30 min and couldn't find any way to do that.

Sure, I can persist all this info myself, but I wouldn't want to resolve to this hackery.

**Edit:** I want to query for these constraints in the code, not an external tool in debug versions of the app.

Thanks.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski, nope, but that's not what I need anyway. I want to query for these constraints in the code, not in any external tool. [edited the answer]

Comment: Have you opened the Workmanager inspector and see the constraints in the jobs db with the db inspector? There is a db within your app storage that contains all jobs scheduled for execution, as far as I remember, that `workspec` table has the constraints as columns. I'm not sure if you can access that without creating your own references (db and dao) to it.

Comment: Yeah, but it is still an existing db within the app space, that you *might* read from it, at least raw query it from within your app.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski, interesting idea. I might give it a try, but it's not a good solution because no one guarantees that the schema of this DB will be consistent across versions.